# How do I sort canvas UI?

Tags: unity

I have a HUD on the UI layer.

It looks like this:

[image]

This HUD overlays the scene.

There are situations where I need to fade out the screen (including the HUD).

To do that, I have added a black image on the UI layer whose alpha value I change.

This fades out the scene, but not the HUD.

What could I do in order to make it so that the HUD is also affected / overlaid by the black image?

This is what the black image looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it:

I have to set the HUD->Canvas->Sort Order to -1.

Comment: Note that Sort Order is available in `Screen Space - Overlay`, but not in `Screen Space - Camera`